# How to open Fancybox without trigger('click')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, fancybox

Can't found way to open Fancybox window http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ with options, and callbacks. Without <s>trigger('click')</s> => this is working WRONG. If try to click usual link in opened fancy window - it just reopend. This is bug.

You can see fancy greeting window here: http://noveogroup-test.esy.es/#

**CODE:**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if (!$.cookie('greeting')) {
        $.cookie('greeting', true);
        $('.greeting').fancybox({
            'beforeLoad': function(){$('.body').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(6px)')},
            'afterClose': function(){$('.body').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(0px)')},
            'openSpeed': 1000,
            'closeSpeed': 500,
            'padding': 20
        }).trigger('click');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: add this line this, `autoPlay : true `

Comment: Does't work. Not starting automaticaly.

Comment: I know, i have to use $.fancybox.open( [group], [options] ), but i doen't understan't where to set callbacks.

Comment: Do it programmatically like `$.fancybox(/* options */)`

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem.

You can trigger click and pass an event which explain « I'm a fancy trigger ». In your listener event click, you will be able to see if it is a manual trigger or a fancy trigger.

```
var eventClick = new $.Event("click"),
    $element = $(".element");

$element.click(function (e) {
    if (e.fancy) {
        return console.log("This is a fancy trigger")
    }

    console.log("This is manual trigger");
});

eventClick.fancy = true;
$element.trigger(eventClick);
```

This is a codepen example : http://codepen.io/Haeresis/pen/RWyxBy